# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Super user with full access to other users directories using FTP

Tags: ubuntu, directory, lts

When creating a user, a directory is created with user name, I want to create a super user, who has access to other users directory, and this using FTP, so when the super user is connected, he has access to all other users directories.

Is there a way to share the user directory with other users ?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that giving FTP full root access would be a very bad idea. Why not give a user root access when they log in (through `ssh`, etc)?

Comment: The problem is that I have end users with no ubuntu or ssh skills, in fact, I have a dedicated server, and multiple user with different access rights, and I want to give each of them ftp access, but i'm struggling with the ftp root access (having access to all other users ftp directories).

Comment: i want to give them access to their files, through the navigator integrated ftp manager, or fillezilla. i hopr i made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user and then edit `/etc/passwd` file and grant root permissions to the user which you created by changing User and Group IDs to UID 0 and GID 0.

For eg.-
You created xyz user, it will look like-

```
# grep xyz /etc/passwd
xyz:x:1001:1001::/home/xyz:/bin/sh
```

Using your favorite text editor, change it to-

```
xyz:x:0:0::/home/xyz:/bin/sh
```

Now since xyz is root, it can have access to all the files.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I mounted a "user2" home folder into a folder created on a "user1" home folder, and now when connecting via ftp, the "user1" can acess "user2" home folder. so i didn't need to create a new user with acess roots. how does it seems to you ?

Comment: Work-around is okay, I guess.